# Hide element using ngFor and ngIf

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to hide the other 3 elements in `li` element after the one of the list was clicked (the clicked list remain unhide), as I try it hide all the `li` element.

payment.component.ts

```
  paymentLists = [
    {
      name: 'IpayEasy',
    },
    {
      name: 'Credit Card',
    },
    {
      name: 'Internet Banking',
    },
    {
      name: '7-Eleven',
    },
  ];

  selectedIndex: number;

  select(index:number) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }
```

payment.component.html

```
  <ul *ngIf="selectedIndex == paymentList">
    <li (click)="select(paymentList)" 
      *ngFor="let paymentList of paymentLists; let i=index">
      <span>{{paymentList.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here what have I tried,
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-list)

Before:

IpayEasy

Credit Card

Internet Banking

7-Eleven (clicked li)

After:

7-Eleven (li element remain unhide)

Comment: If index (and selectedIndex) is a number and paymentList is an array, how can selectedIndex ever be equal to an array?

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-list-pysyaj

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your template as following

- Move ngFor to ng-container element
- Update ngIf condition to be true only if there is no selected index or the matching selected index
- Pass index in `select` function

Updated html will be as follows

```
<ul>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let paymentList of paymentLists; let i=index" >
       <li (click)="select(i)"  *ngIf="selectedIndex === undefined || selectedIndex == i" [ngClass]="{'tab__list--selected--mobile': selectedIndex == paymentList}">
          <span>{{paymentList.name}}</span>
       </li>
   </ng-container>
</ul>
```

For reference, here is the [working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-list-5lgse7?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  <ul *ngIf="selectedIndex == paymentList">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let paymentList of paymentLists; let i=index">
      <li (click)="select(paymentList)" *ngIf="!selectedIndex || selectedIndex=i">
        <span>{{paymentList.name}}</span>
      </li>
    </ng-container>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead of yours :

your ts:

```
  select(index) {
     this.paymentLists = [index];
  }
```

your HTML:

```
 <ul *ngIf="selectedIndex == paymentList">
    <li (click)="select(paymentList)" 
    *ngFor="let paymentList of paymentLists; let i=index">
      <span>{{paymentList.name}}</span>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, Since my previous answer wasn't very clear. Here is a thorough explanation to the solution for the aforementioned problem.

```
paymentLists = [
    {
      name: 'IpayEasy',
    },
    {
      name: 'Credit Card',
    },
    {
      name: 'Internet Banking',
    },
    {
      name: '7-Eleven',
    },
  ];

  selectedIndex: number;

  select(index:number) {
    this.selectedIndex = this.paymentLists.findIndex(x => x.name==paymentListNameObject.name);
    this.paymentListSelected = true;
  }
```

in the above mentioned code, the select function recieves an object instead of the index number. which can be corrected as above. Also i added a variable paymentListSelected. this variable tracks if a particular payment method has been selected.

In the HTML, you could get rid of `*ngIf="selectedIndex == paymentList"` and use the following:

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let paymentList of paymentLists; let i=index" (click)="select(paymentList)" 
          [ngClass]="{'tab__list--selected--mobile': ((i == selectedIndex)&&paymentListSelected),'hide-tab__list--unselected--mobile': paymentListSelected}">
          <span>{{paymentList.name}}</span>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

Here i add 2 classes `tab__list--selected--mobile` which is applied to the selected payment method based on the index number which was selected by the user. And to hide the other options, i added `hide-tab__list--unselected--mobile` to all other options.

Finally here is a working link just in case the explanation wasn't clear enough.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-display-list-d19ffv

This answer i guess qualifies for not getting DELETED!!!!!